# How to set first day of week in DatePicker?

Tags: sapui5

How to set (customize) first day of week in `sap.m.DatePicker`'s calendar?  I can change the first day of week in `sap.ui.unified.calendar`, but not for `sap.m.DatePicker`? Any ideas? I have my sample SAPUI5 plnkr

[image: here].

Answer (score 1):

you can access the internal calendar in your handleChange function via:

```
handleChange: function(evt){
   evt.oSource._oCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(1); 
}
```

But this is not the way it meant to be accessed. There is no official way to access the internal calendar of the Datepicker. So my advise would be to open up a feature request on openui5 via github https://github.com/SAP/openui5/ .

Comment: it may not work on first click on date picker, might work on subsequent clicks. can we access this on view's oninit?

Comment: I checked the sourcecode of the Datepicker and the internal calendar gets instantiated when the popup is called:
`DatePicker.prototype._createPopupContent = function(){

  if (!this._oCalendar) {
   sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("sap.ui.unified");
   jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified.library");
   this._oCalendar = new sap.ui.unified.Calendar(this.getId() + "-cal", {
    intervalSelection: this._bIntervalSelection,
    minDate: this.getMinDate(),
    maxDate: this.getMaxDate(),
    legend: this.getLegend()
    });`
So there is currently no chance to access this onInit!

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem and I resolved it [extending](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d5b756bf4e9a4d67961fa21e1ba12c9e) (see also this [tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/19/how-to-extend-a-standard-ui5-control/) to extend ui5-control) *sap.m.DatePicker* in order to create a new one. Then I have extended *_createPopupContent* method in the following manner:

```
MyNewDatePicker.prototype._createPopupContent = function() {
    DatePicker.prototype._createPopupContent.call(this);
    ...
    this._oCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set it for all date pickers in your application you can do the following:

`sap.ui.core.LocaleData.getInstance(sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().getFormatLocale()).mData["weekData-firstDay"] = 1;`

see https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/15733085#15733085

There may be a way to set this for all apps under Fiori Launch Pad but I have not found that trick.